# companionlibrary compilation error

Tags: android, android-appcompat, google-cast

Iam working with the Google Cast Git hub project -[CastVideos-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android)

I have setup dependencies in to the eclipse workplace.(Running on latest sdk update)

> ```
>  google-play-services_lib library from the Android SDK (at least version 7.0+)
>  android-support-v7-appcompat (version 21 or above)
>  android-support-v7-mediarouter (version 20 or above)
> ```

These Library files does not display any errors

[image]

But when  iam adding companionlibrary to the workplace it displaying these errors.

```
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] D:\Google   CAst\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:88: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] 
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] D:\Google CAst\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:85: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] 
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] D:\Google CAst\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:86: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] 
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] D:\Google CAst\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:136: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] 
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] D:\Google CAst\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:140: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] 
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] D:\Google CAst\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
  [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] 
  [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] D:\Google CAst\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:139: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] 
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] D:\Google CAst\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:137: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] 
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] D:\Google CAst\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:134: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] 
 [2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] D:\Google CAst\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:135: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] 
[2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] D:\Google CAst\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:144: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
[2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] 
[2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter] D:\Google CAst\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:148: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
[2015-04-30 11:16:45 - android-support-v7-mediarouter]
```

I have updated all projects in to latest Support library,and android-support-v4.jar is not contain any of lib folder of above projects.(i saw that this may case to this type of errors) These are my project. proprieties files

**android-support-v7-appcompat**

```
target=android-21
android.library=true
```

**android-support-v7-mediarouter**

```
 target=android-21
 android.library=true
 android.library.reference.1=../android-support-v7-appcompat
```

**google-play-services_lib**

```
target=android-21
android.library=true
```

here is my sdk manager
[image]

Comment: any ideas to solve this

Comment: If possible, please move to Android Studio since now that is the supported IDE for Android Development; work on the eclipse plugin for Android has stopped and it is no longer supported/maintained.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the Android Support Library to 22.1.1 and Android Support Repository 14 via SDK manager.After that try to import the new android-support-v7-appcompact and use it in you project.

Comment: i have updated sdk before importing libraries..please see my edited post